# Appended item is instantly removed

Tags: javascript, event-listener, appendchild

I am trying to understand the basics of eventListeners, i have created a simple form where i just want to add a value of an input to a UL, however when i append the value, i am able to see it in the list for a brief second and then it is instantly removed, i cannot figure out why, could anyone help?.

```
const submitButton = document.querySelector('#add-task-btn');
const clearButton = document.querySelector('#remove-task-btn');
const item = document.querySelector('#task');
const taskList = document.querySelector('.collection');

allEventListeners();

function allEventListeners(){

    submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(){

        if (item.value === ''){
            alert('Please add a task')
        };

        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.value));

        taskList.appendChild(li);

        item.value = "";

    })
}
```

Comment: can you share your html?

Comment: The submit button causes the form to be submitted and reload the page…?!

Comment: As @deceze pointed out, the button is firing a submit event. You need to use `ev.preventDefault()` in your eventHandler function

Comment: yes @deceze it is reloaded, here is a link to the html

https://codepen.io/ShrewdStyle/pen/MWYPMyV?editors=1010

Comment: you can do the preventDefault thing, or, just don't use a form if you don't intend on submitting a form. I mean, would you use a video tag if your page didn't have a video?

Comment: @Jackson thank you, i did not pass anything into my function so after passing ev and using your suggested ev.preventDefault() at the bottom it has worked, what does the preventDefault do?

Comment: @Jackson can you post as an answer so i can mark it as completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to provide an event parameter for your handler function and then call `preventDefault()`

```
submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault(); // prevent the page submit

  //...

});
```